# SmtpClient SendAsync ожидание 'void' невозможно

Tags: c#, .net, sendmail, async-await

Пробую использовать асинхронный метод `SendAsync` у `SmtpClient`

```
public async Task SentMessageAsync(ApplicationUser user, string title, string text)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(SiteFromAdress, new MailAddress(user.Email));

    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.Subject = title;
    mail.Body = text;

    await smtpClient.SendAsync(mail, new object());
}
```

Там где `await smtpClient.SendAsync` студия ругается на `ожидание 'void' невозможно`.

Можно вообще как-то сделать отправку писем асинхронно? И почему ругается студия?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что это асинхронный метод из старой модели [EAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wewwczdw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (event-based asynchronous programming). Метод `SendAsync()` просто запускает отправку и завершает работу. Узнать об окончании отправки можно подписавшись на событие `SendCompleted`. Из [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x5x13z6h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(args[0]);
client.SendCompleted += SendCompletedCallback;
client.SendAsync(message, userState);

...

private void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Если вы хотите использовать async/await, воспользуйтесь методом `SendMailAsync()`.

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось что `smtpClient.SendAsync` - устаревшая функция

вместо неё надо использовать `smtpClient.SendMailAsync(mail)` и она уже возвращает Task  и с ней можно работать ассинхронно.